# Can one make ice on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, water

Can one make ice on Shabbat? 
For example, putting water in an empty ice cube box and freezing it?

I've heard it's a Machloket between the Rema and Shulchan Arukh. What are their opinions on making ice on Shabbat?

Comment: Very clear summary of the issues here: http://vbm-torah.org/archive/hilshabbat/13hilshabbat.htm

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3721

Comment: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/dash-part-5-freezing-and-thawing-ice#_ftnref6 RJBS thought it might be boneh

Answer (score 9):

Yechave Da'as 1:30 rules that one may make ice cubes on Shabbos

Shmiras Shabbos K'hilchoso 10:5 footnote 15 in the name of the Tchbiner Rav says it is forbidden because of Nolad, however in 10:4 footnote 14 mentions that others permit it.

However even according to those that permit making ice on Shabbos, one may only make ice if it will be used on that Shabbos.

Comment: Is there any discussion regarding this exact topic in the SA?

Comment: @user8553 If you have a copy of Yechave Da'as or Shmiras Shabbos K'hilchoso, they'll cite their sources as footnotes.

Comment: Especially Yechave Daas

Answer (score 6):

Rav Eliyashiv (Vayishma Moshe p. 131) is quoted as holding that making ice on shabbat is assur because of [boneh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_prohibited_on_Shabbat#Building). (Footnote 175 brings the Dovev Meisharim 1:55 who holds it assur because of [nolad](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/hilshabbat/13hilshabbat.htm). See also Tzitz Eliezer 6:34).

[Rav Ribiat in *39 Melochos*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001O246H6) brings in the notes (fn. 175, in [dosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_prohibited_on_Shabbat#Threshing.2FExtraction), among others) cites *Sefer Hilchos Shabbas*, which writes that he heard from the mouth of Rav Moshe Feinstein that putting water into a freezer on shabbas to make ice he doesn't see a place to assur it, especially in a time of need. For example, when one has guests there is what to be matir.

Answer (score 6):

One of the prominent poskim of the past generation, R. Dov Berish Weidenfeld, who was the Tshebiner Rav and author of Dovev Meisharim, ruled that freezing water to make ice cubes on Shabbos is not permitted due to the prohibition of molid (creating a new entity), or nolad (benefitting from something that came into existence on Shabbos). Other poskim argue that it might be similar to the melachah of boneh (using existing ingredients to construct something).

However, the majority of poskim rejected both these positions, and ruled that making ice cubes on Shabbos is permitted, provided they are intended for use on Shabbos. In a case where there is a tzorech (need), there is even more room for leniency, as the Rama tends to be lenient regarding similar aspects of nolad on Shabbos and Yom Tov if there is a tzorech. Obviously, this discussion doesn’t refer to an automatic ice-maker which is forbidden to be used on Shabbos and Yom Tov.

בסוגיא זו דנו כו״כ אחרונים מכמה צדדים. ואא״פ להעתיק כל המובא בעניננו, כי האר״ש רחבת ידים היא, ואין לנו אלא לצטט עיקרי הדברים, וראיתם את האר״ש מה היא, כי מציו״ן תצא תורה, בספרי המלקטים שבנו אצלם ציו״ן המצויינת.

ונקודת הדברים, שכשאינו מרסק בידים והוא נימוח מאליו, קייל״ן (רמ״א סשי״ח סט״ז. אדה״ז שם סכ״ז) שבמקום הצורך אפי׳ לכתחילה יש להקל.

ובפי׳ צורך כאן – כ׳ הלבוש ״צורך אורחין וכה״ג״. ולכאו׳ כל שהוא צורך שבת – ג״ז בכלל. וכ״ה להדיא במשנ״ב בשעה״צ ס״ק קלג. וכ״כ בשו״ת צי״א ח״ו סל״ד סקי״א (לעניננו – הקפאת נוזלים). ואילה״ק שלפ״ז הכל בכלל, ומהו פשר ד׳ הרמ״א (שם סט״ז) שנהגו להחמיר – שהרי יל״פ באופן שיש לו מאכלים שנימוחו כבר. וגם פשטות ד׳ הרמ״א מיירי גם בדברים שאינם אוכלים, ואי״ב משום עונג וצורך שבת. [ובשבת כהלכה ח״ג פיז בבי׳ סקי״ב אזיל בתר איפכא, ודעתו דעת נוטה שצ״ל צורך גמור. ודייק בלישנא בשו״ת דובב מישרים ח״א סנ״ה שכ׳ ״לצורך גדול״. ולא ניחא להו למארייהו למימר הכי, ולדייק כ״כ בלשון הרהמ״ח הנ״ל. ונראים הדברים דאגב שיטפי׳ נקט הכי].

וכעת ניהדר אנפין לנדו״ד – הנה בשבה״ש (מעשה חושב דיני מלאכה שאינה לקיום ס״ב) הב״ד בעל פתה״ד (סשכ״ה סק״א) לאסור באופן ההקפאה שבימיהם משום נולד ובונה. ובשבה״ש הקשה עליו משה״ק. ולהוסיף, דהתם מיירי בדעביד עובדא, ולא כשנעשה מאליו וממילא, כבימינו.

ואף ששו״ת דובב מישרים הנ״ל ר״ל שחמור יותר מהמסת שומן, עיי״ש סברתו – מ״מ להלכה למעשה לא נתקבלה סברתו. והאריכו באחרונים בכמה טעמים לחלק בין הדבקים. וכ״פ להתיר בשו״ת מהרש״ג ח״ב סק״ג. ראה בהנסמן בשבת כהלכה פי״ז סצ״ג ואילך. ועיי״ש שבכמה אופנים המצויים, גם לדעת המחמירים מותר. וראה גם בהנסמן בפסקי תשובות סש״כ (מהדו״ח) סקט״ז. בנין שלום סש״כ ס״ט ע׳ קמד ואילך.

ובשערים מצויינים בהלכה לאאזמו״ר זצ״ל (סי׳ פ סקי״ח) הוסיף טעם לשבח במציאות ימינו שהקרח משמש בד״כ עבור משקה. וראה גם בשו״ת אמרי אברהם או״ח סי״ז.

ועייג״כ בשו״ת צי״א הנ״ל בארוכה שביסס טעמי ההיתר. ובפרט ע״פ דעת אדה״ז בשולחנו (סשי״ח סכ״ה) בגדר האיסור. ואמור רבנן בכפיל״א – ראה גם מש״כ שם עוד (ח״ח סי״ב).

ובאמת, כמעט מפורש הדבר להיתר, דקייל״ן (שו״ע או״ח סשי״ח ס״ג) שמותר ליתן ביצה בחמה, אף שנהפכת מנוזל לגוש. ולכאו׳ זו ראי׳ שאין עלי׳ תשובה.

ובדיעבד, ודאי שאין מקום לאיסור גם שלא במקום צורך, לדעת אדה״ז שם שטעם האיסור בדיעבד הוא משום גזירת משקין שזבו, וכ״ז ל״ש בנדוננו. (ואוי״ל ג״כ שבמקום דל״ש גזירת משקין שזבו בדיעבד, לא גזרו משום מוליד גם לכתחילה. אלא שלא מצאתי סימוכין לסברא זו).

ובקובץ תפארת יהודה קלמן ע׳ 423 כ׳ לדייק מל׳ אדה״ז לאסור איסר בעניננו. ואין דבריו מוכרחים כלל כאשר יראה כל ישר הולך.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above answers are fantastic - I just wanted to share this great story to help remember Rav Moshe Feinstein's psak halacha: When Rav Heinemann asked Rav Moshe this question regarding making ice on shabbos, Rav Moshe said "Of course, we made ice all the time in Europe." This prompted Rav Heinemann to ask how they managed to make ice easily without freezers, to which Rav Moshe replied, "We would put the cup of water on the windowsill, and after some time it would become ice."

This anecdotal psak from Rav Heinemann is [echoed](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Molid#Crushing_and_melting_ice) by Halachapedia

> The Shabbos Kitchen 177 footnote 22 quotes Or Hashabbos 4:107 in the
>   name of Rav Moshe that you can make ice because it has no permanence.