# Making a Slurpee/Slushee on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food

Although this *might* be the same [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52863/can-one-make-ice-on-shabbos) as making ice cubes on Shabbos, is it permitted to make a Slurpee/Slushee on Shabbos using the [following](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IGLQACW) method: a specialized ice-pack is left in the freezer for a few hours then inserted into a soft silicone cup. After pouring soda into the ice-pack/silicone cup combination, the soda takes on a slush partial liquid/ice consistency after squeezing the cup.