# Is putting food in the freezer on Shabbos a machloket?

Tags: shabbat, food

What is the Halacha if one wanted to put food in the freezer that could be used for a later date? Would this be considered Hachana for after Shabbos? Would this be considered a machloket, since usually one would be allowed to put food in the freezer but if they say that they are planning on using it for a later time then it would not be allowed. So overall I want to know if putting food in the freezer would be considered a machloket if it is allowed or not. 
Thanks!

Comment: Why ask about freezer and not refrigerator?

Comment: Because of food came out of fridge then putting it back in its place wouldn't be hachana according to most poskim. However, placing food for the first time in the freezer would be a whole other discussion.

Comment: SKA student - from 5 Towns area?

Comment: I think in our religion it would be safe to answer any question of if something is a machloket with a clear 'yes'. :)

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52863/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a machlokes . From the Sefer Bnei Avraham.

For the stringent opinions would include the Sefer Sharei Yosher 2:55:9,Rivevos Ephraim ,Teshuvos Vhanagos 1:227,Rav Shlomo Miller (holds since it changes into a harder thing it's hachana- Magen Avraham 321:7).

Lenient opinions ,Maharshag siman 61 ( If there will be a loss then it isn't hachana, rather hatzalah.  Minchas Yitzchak 8:24 bases off this Maharshag. Yalkut Yosef 2:hachana:22,Olas Yitzchak 1:57. AzNidabru 12:31.

With regards to an issue of nolad with putting soup in freezer would also be machlokes ,some would be stringent while other would be meikel.

Answer (score 0):

If one puts liquid into a freezer (putting solid in the freezer is permitted as there is no *Nolad* -New substance)for a time that will cause the liquid to freeze inorder to benefit on shabbos, this is a *Machlokes* whether considdered a Melacha derabanan or not.

The Mishna brura Orach Chaim 320,9 33 gives 2 diferent reasons why השלג והברד אין מרסקין אותם  melting ice with ones hands into liquid is prohibitted:
1. דדמי למלאכה שבורא המים הללו ואסור מדרבנן - He is "creating" water *Nolad* which is prohibited Miderabanan
2. א"נ גזירה שמא יסחוט פירות העומדין למשקין: - Alternatively we make a decree of Pressing ice in case he will press fruit juice which is prohibited as a derivative Melacha of *Dosh* -Threshing

So if the reason why melting ice is forbidden is because of creating a knew substance, one cannot put liquid in the freezer as a solid is created. This is the opinion of Rashi Shabbos 51b and the Tur Orach chaim 320.

But if there is only a prohibition of pressing solids to make liquids come out i.e it looks like *Dosh*, it would be permitted to make liquids into solids as this is not *dash*. Indeed the Magen avraham cites the Magid Mishna Ramban and Ran who do forbid changing a solid into liquid actively because of *dash*. This only applies when one cna see the water coming out of the ice, however if one presses ice in a cup of water where one cannot see the water come out or melting in the sun or other passive methods it would be ok as this does not look like Threshing.

The Mishna Brura concludes that *Nolad* is forbidden based on the Rena:

> ולדעת רמ"א בסימן שי"ח סט"ז בהג"ה גם הכא יש להחמיר דאף דנימוח מאליו אסור משום נולד

Comment: @ska i see you have an answer which deals with preparing for after Shabbos which satisfies you, but you may want to take a look on my answer which deals with freezing liquid for the sake of Shabbos.

Comment: Your citation of the Magen Avraham seems unclear. It may just need some punctuation or there might be a missing word, but it's hard to tell what you are asserting with that. My understanding of the Magen Avraham is that he cites those authorities as saying that the reason melting ice is forbidden is שמא יסחוט, but there is no such gezeira when melting the ice into a cup of liquid. Thus it would be permissible to *actively* melt ice as long as you do it into a cup of liquid, and it would also be permissible to passively melt ice even not in a cup of liquid.

Comment: @alex i meant like you said i missed a few words just edited so feel free to look at my edit