# Does casting metal entail a melacha (assuming it's already liquid)?

Tags: melacha-creative-work, maseches-shabbos

The Torah says to [cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_(metalworking)) gold rings when building the Mishkan. Obviously you'd have to do the melachos of *extinguishing* to make charcoal, *burning* to then ignite said charcoal, and *cooking* to liquefy the gold.

At that point, the remaining steps are to pour the molten gold into a mold and then remove it from the mold.

Does casting in and of itself constitute a Biblical melacha? Is it *makeh b'patish* (a term literally invoking forging, more than casting)? Or something else?

Comment: Could be _writing_ if the cast makes a particular shape/design

Comment: Makeh b'patish seems the most likely candidate, similar to the way glassblowing falls under that category (Rambam, Hil. Shabbos 10:16) - and in both cases the item is still too hot to use yet.

Comment: dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52863/759