Are you allowed to make liquid nitrogen ice cream on Yom Tov
Liquid nitrogen is a liquid version of nitrogen gas and hence very cold. This ice cream involves sugar, chocolate syrup, milk --liquid nitrogen is poured in as one stirs vigorously. When all have evaporated, what left is soft ice cream--ready to eat.

How does one manifest liquid nitrogen on Yom Tov? Does one have a freezer set to -200 degrees celsius?

duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3721/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52863/759

@DoubleAA the references are not using liquid nitrogen which evaporates. Is there an issue of nolad with using liquid nitrogen?

@YDJ The nolad issue is the milk become solid by whatever coolant.

Welcome to MiYodeya Miriam and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
